# If $L^*=L^3$, then $L^2$ is diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $L\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a $n\times n$ matrix. Assume that $L^T=L^3$. Show that $L^2$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$.

My try: Since $L^T=L^3$, then 
$$
LL^T=L^4=L^TL.
$$
Thus, $L$ is a normal matrix and $L^4$ is a positive semi-definite matrix. Thus, $L$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$ and $L^4$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$. But how to show that $L^2$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $L$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then (using the hermitian inner product)
$$\bar\lambda\|v\|^2 = \langle v,Lv\rangle = \langle L^\top v,v\rangle = \langle L^3v,v\rangle = \lambda^3\|v\|^2.$$
Thus, $\lambda^3=\bar\lambda$, so $|\lambda|=0$ or $|\lambda|=1$. In the latter case, we have $\lambda^3 = 1/\lambda$, so $\lambda^4=1$ and $\lambda^2 = \pm 1$, as needed.

Comment: So, all the eigenvalues of $L^2$ are real numbers. Does this mean $L^2$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$? I thought we need to prove there exists a real matrix $O$ such that $O^*L^2O$ is a real diagonal matrix.

Comment: Sure. There is a basis consisting of (complex) eigenvectors of the real matrix $L$. Those eigenvectors are, of course, also eigenvectors of the real matrix $L^2$. But since $L^2$ has only real eigenvalues, its eigenvectors are (can be chosen to be) real, right, since they come from solving a system of linear equations over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you very much!